# Rewrite rule in nginx error

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

What is wrong in this rule?

```
 rewrite ^/view/?([^/.]+)?/?([^/.]+)?.html /view_video.php?id=$1 last;
```

I changed from:

```
RewriteRule ^view/?([^/\.]+)?/?([^/\.]+)?\.html view_video.php?id=$1  [L,QSA]
```

My link must be:

```
./view/14/name_of_video.html
```